# HIVE SELECT FROM 3 TABLES

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

```
Table 1:
  - user_id
  - item_id
  - time
  - day
Table 2:
  - user_id
  - phone no
Table 3:
  - create_time
  - phone no
```

I have to get all item_ids from Table 1 where user_id matches with Table 2 and the create_time from table 3 is greater than a particular date(x) where day in table 1 is 18th August

Can someone help me with query?

Comment: have you tried writing any code yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your table structure, the relationship between Table2 and Table3 is phone no. ?

Try this query:

```
enter code here
SELECT * FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.user_id = Table2.user_id
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.[phone no] = Table3.[phone no]
```

WHERE Table3.[create_time] < RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(08),Table3.[create_time],112),4) = '0818'
AND Table1.[Day] = RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(08),Table1.[Day],112),4) = '0818'

Also, when you creating column name, best practice that you don't have spaces, make it one word. That's why I put bracket [], when I JOIN the table2 and table3 to avoid errors.

Comment: There is one more condition for table 3 that the create_time should be less than 18th Aug and the day from table 1 should be 18th August. How do i include these?

Comment: @SavinayNarendra , assuming that the datatype of your Day in table 1 is datetime., i also assume that the datatype of your create_time in table3 is datetime too. -Regards :)

Comment: Actually both are strings. day in table 1 is stored as 'yyyy-mm-dd' and create_time in table 3 is stored as 'unix_timestamp'. Is it okay to compare string directly with big int. I am taking timestamp for 18th Aug and comparing.